# How to remove the Deprecated property of __construct from Abstract Class using overriding or any other way

Tags: magento2, overrides, dependency-injection, admin-controller, abstract-class

**Error**

> main.ERROR: Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property
> Magiccart\Magicproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Index\Interceptor::$_resultRedirectFactory
> is deprecated in
> vendor/magiccart/magicproduct/Controller/Adminhtml/Action.php on line
> 78

**Class namespace Magiccart\Magicproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Action**

```
abstract class Action extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action  {      
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultRedirectFactory = $context->getResultRedirectFactory();
    }
```

**Class Magiccart\Magicproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Index**

```
class Index extends \Magiccart\Magicproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax')) {
            $resultForward = $this->_resultForwardFactory->create();
            $resultForward->forward('grid');

            return $resultForward;
        }

        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Current Solution**
I have tried to override it using preference and than remove the line 78

```
$this->_resultRedirectFactory = $context->getResultRedirectFactory();
```

but still it is showing the same error (But if i do direct change in code this issue get fixed)

```
class Custom\Magicproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\CustomAction**

    abstract class CustomAction extends \Magiccart\Magicproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Product
{
```

**Another way**

```
<type name="Magiccart\Magicproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Action">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="_resultRedirectFactory" xsi:type="string">nothing</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

But Nothing works and same error appearing again

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the property $_resultPageFactory in the class. It should resolve the issue.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
**/
private \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $_resultPageFactory
```

Since this is a third-party extension there is no other way to fix this without overriding it. You can wait for them to release a PHP 8.2 compatible version of this extension or you can temporarily override it and fix it for the time being until the vendor fixes it themselves. Instead of declaring property you can also use:

> #[AllowDynamicProperties]

It is not recommended though as with PHP 9 this will also be deprecated and dynamic property allocation will start throwing Fatal errors.

Downgrading PHP to the version before 8.2 is also another option that way you won't have to override anything.

Comment: But this is the 3rd party Module how can I override or add this in my new module ?

Comment: You have already overridden it right? Here:
"Current Solution I have tried to override it using preference and than remove the line 78"